# ngModel binding one key stroke late

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive. Here is the plunker of the directive: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5M6U8f?p=preview)

the ngModel value is one key stoke late than display: e.g. if i have display value "abc" then the ngModel received by ngChange function is "ab".

What i dont understand is.. the value I am printing on screen and the value I am passing to the ngChange both are same ngModel, then how can they have different values??

Please help!!!

**EDIT**

I am currently receiving the ngChange using '&' its one key stroke late.. but if i receive ngChange using '=' the values are in sync but ngChange is called too many times..

I have updated the plunker to show the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the value to be passed to ng-change should be $viewValue and not $modalValue, because $viewValue not always makes it to $modalValue...

Answer (score 1):

To call a function inside the controller or parent scope from inside a directive with isolate scope, you need to pass an object:

```
<cs-input options="fields.userId" ng-model="abc.userId" 
ng-change="changeFunction(userId)"></cs-input>
```

JS

```
return '<input type="text" name="myfield" ' +
        'data-ng-change="ngChange({userId:ngModel})" data-ng-model="ngModel"/>';
```

Comment: but then, i don't know in the directive the parameters with which the function is going to get called from the html markup, user can pass any parameters...

Comment: It is the model that is passed as a parameter. Just give the solution a shot.

Comment: there was an issue with the plunker: ng-model="abc.userId" ng-change="changeFunction(userId)" the parameter in ng-model and ng-change are different - missing prefix abc, i added that prefix and its again not working

Comment: no need of prefixing the parameter..it has to be the same as the parameter name in the controller function.

Comment: ok got it. it works. but it still feels like a hack because but my directive is no more generic, i need to know the name of the parameter wherever the directive is being used

Answer (score 0):

You already have ngModel, why do you still need ngChange? You can use $watch instead.

http://plnkr.co/edit/85Su4Dewc0kpXttuY9sp?p=preview

```
  $scope.id = 'x';
  $scope.$watch('id', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.watchedNewValue = newValue;
    $scope.watchedOldValue = oldValue;
  });
```